# How to push RTSP stream to wowza

Tags: video-streaming, rtsp, rtp, wowza, server-push

I have a  rapberry-pi connected to  a webcam, which sits behind a NAT/firewall. I need an app running on raspberry-pi to establish a connection with [wowza](http://www.wowza.com/) and stream the webcam feed over RTSP.

Is this possible? I think RTSP supports both  "client pull" and "server push". But I am not able to find any information regarding the "server push" mechanism.

Is this the correct vlc command to setup server push:

```
vlc -vvv v4l2:///dev/video0 :v4l2-standard= :input-slave=alsa://hw:0,0 :live-caching=300 sout:#transcode{vcodec=h264,acodec=mpga,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100}:rtp{sdp=rtsp://:8554/hi.mp4} :sout-keep
```

But I am unable to setup vlc in client mode to view the stream.

My aim is to do this for wowza. But I am testing locally with vlc now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for different way answer.

I recommend you ffmpeg. It's more powerful when you push stream to wowza.

here is simple sample

- codec Copy(No transcoding)
  ffmpeg -i rtsp://your_url -vcodec copy -acodec copy -f rtsp rtsp://wowza-ip:1935/live/test.stream
- codec libx264(Transcoding)
  ffmpeg -i rtsp://your_url -vcodec libx264 -s 1280x720 -r 30 -g 15 -b 2048k -acodec copy -f rtsp rtsp://wowza-ip:1935/live/test.stream

I hope to resolve problem

Comment: -acodec copy : if you want to no audio, "-acodec copy" -> "-an"

Comment: -s : resolution
-r : fps
-g : i frame interval 
-f : format